# C++ Trouble with passing functions (math doesn't add up)

Tags: c++, function, parameters, radius

I have an assignment in c++ where I have to find the radius, circumference and the area of a circle. I *think* I've managed to pass the functions correctly, but maybe not, because the program refuses to display the correct area and circumference of the circle, in spite of calling up the radius as a parameter. I plug in my formulas for circumference and area, and the program spits back numbers that are completely off. anyway, here's my code below, any help would be so appreciated. Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

//declare prototypes

float radius_of_circle(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2);
float distance(float xxx1, float yyy1, float xxx2, float yyy2);
float circum(float distance);
float area(float area_of_circle);

int main ()
{
    float x1, y1, x2, y2;

    // prompt the user 

    cout << "Please enter the first X value below " << endl;
    cin >> x1;
    cout << "Now enter the first Y value below" << endl;
    cin >> y1;
    cout << "Please enter the second X value below " << endl;
    cin >> x2;
    cout << "Now enter the second Y value below " << endl;
    cin >> y2;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;

    //display the center and point of the circle

    cout << "The CENTER of the circle is...(" << x1 << " , " << y1 << ")" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "A POINT on the circle is...(" << x2 << " , " << y2 << ")" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    // create new function to call 

    float dist = distance(x1, y1, x2, y1);





    cout << " The Distance between the points is..." << radius_of_circle(x1, y1, x2, y2) << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << " The Radius of the Circle is..." << radius_of_circle(x1, y1, x2, y2) << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << " The Circumference of Circle is... " << circum(dist) << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << " The Area of Circle is... : " << area(dist) << endl;
    cout << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;

}

//radius function

float distance (float xx1, float yy1, float xx2, float yy2) {

    int distancex = pow(xx2 - xx1, 2);
    int distancey = pow(yy2 - yy1, 2);
    return sqrt(distancex + distancey);
}


// distance function

float radius_of_circle(float xxx1, float yyy1, float xxx2, float yyy2) {
    return distance(xxx1, yyy1, xxx2, yyy2);

}


//circumference function

float circum(float distance)
{

    return 2 * 3.1416 * distance;
}

//area function

float area(float distance) {

    return 3.1416 * pow(distance, 2) ;
}
```

thank you for such quick replies...here is the output. apparently the radius calculates correctly but the area and circumference and not. thanks.

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3RkY.png)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that shows the inputs giving you bad results

Comment: 1) What is example input, expected, and actual outputs? 2) Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: `float dist = distance(x1, y1, x2, y1);` has a typo which will cause bad results..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: If you don't have a debugger get an IDE like Visual Studio that has a good debugger and learn how to single step through your code in your debugger.

Comment: oh f*** me, @drescherjm THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!     solved!

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but you really don't need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. `'\n'` ends a line. And when you're prompting for input you might consider not ending the line: `std::cout << "first X value: "; std::cin >> x1;`.

Comment: @PeteBecker hi, Id actually really like to know how to put multiple inputs on one line, but I can never properly seperate the values, they always run in together and look messy or look like one big number which can be confusing. Do you Know what I mean?

Answer (score 1):

Your bug is here

```
float dist = distance(x1, y1, x2, y1);
```

notice the last parameter. You have `y1` instead of  `y2`

The code should be

```
float dist = distance(x1, y1, x2, y2);
```

Comment: Thank you sir, feeling dumbo but glad I can pass it in now :)